# Filter NSArray by string in nested object

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, filter, nsarray

I have an array of objects that I need to filter. I know that I should b using NSPredicate but can't seem to find an answer to filtering by a string in an object, inside of another object.

Here is what a single object of the array looks like:

```
{
    "data_center"
    {
        "id":1,
        "site_id":17,
        "name":"Building",
        "shortname":"ORL-Building",
        "created_at":"2011-10-28T06:32:39Z",
        "updated_at":"2011-10-28T06:32:39Z",
        "site":
        {
            "id":17,
            "name":"Orlando",
            "shortname":"ORL"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I filter the Array using Site.name in the nested object? The array itself is an NSArray which requires filteredArrayUsingPredicate:.

Also, The way that I am finding the data to filter the array by is by pulling it from a UIPickerView, So I have to retrieve the object that was used from a different pickerview, and filter a second array based on the string for site name.

I couldn't seem to find a good answer to this one, If anyone has any advice I would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predicates can use keypaths to navigate into the data structure, so you could do something like:

```
@"data_center.site.name LIKE %@", name
```

You could also look at using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` to build the list of items that you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry, what I posted was the original JSON response. The array is dataCentersArray with a data center object, that has a nested site object. But this does give me an idea.